# localhost:3000 not loading webpage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, mean-stack

I have had this problem a few times and am looking for help. I am working on a small example web app using the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, Angular2, and NodeJS) every time I stop npm start and stop my mongo database when I try to start back up again Chrome gives me the "Aw, Snap!" error because "Something went wrong while displaying this webpage." Also in the console it is telling me:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at new ViewWrappedError (eval at  (http://localhost:3000/js/app/bundle.js:1740:1), :77:16)
>       at _View_AppComponent0.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (eval at  (http://localhost:3000/js/app/bundle.js:2651:1), :411:23)

With many more errors, all  happening in the bundle.js file.

Any ideas on why my app wont start on localhost? Below is the bundle.js

```js
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/  // The module cache
/******/  var installedModules = {};

/******/  // The require function
/******/  function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/   // Check if module is in cache
/******/   if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/    return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/   // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/   var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/    i: moduleId,
/******/    l: false,
/******/    exports: {}
/******/   };

/******/   // Execute the module function
/******/   modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/   // Flag the module as loaded
/******/   module.l = true;

/******/   // Return the exports of the module
/******/   return module.exports;
/******/  }


/******/  // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/  __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/  // expose the module cache
/******/  __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/  // identity function for calling harmory imports with the correct context
/******/  __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };

/******/  // define getter function for harmory exports
/******/  __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/   Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/    configurable: false,
/******/    enumerable: true,
/******/    get: getter
/******/   });
/******/  };

/******/  // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/  __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/   var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/    function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/    function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/   __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/   return getter;
/******/  };

/******/  // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/  __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };

/******/  // __webpack_public_path__
/******/  __webpack_require__.p = "/js/app/";

/******/  // Load entry module and return exports
/******/  return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 579);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__src_core__ = __webpack_require__(372);\n/* harmony namespace reexport */ for(var __WEBPACK_IMPORT_KEY__ in __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__src_core__) if(__WEBPACK_IMPORT_KEY__ !== 'default') (function(key) { __webpack_require__.d(exports, key, function() { return __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__src_core__[key]; }) }(__WEBPACK_IMPORT_KEY__));\n/**\n * @license\n * Copyright Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.\n *\n * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be\n * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license\n */\n/**\n * @module\n * @description\n * Entry point for all public APIs of the core package.\n */\n\n//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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");

/***/ },
```

Comment: I suggest you post a minimal test case. Some source code + configuration that will reproduce this. Without it, you're unlikely to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` indicates there is a recursive function that has called itself too many times. The limit is [relatively small](http://www.2ality.com/2014/04/call-stack-size.html) (10k - 50k). Most likely, it is either operating on a highly nested data structure or it doesn't have good exit criteria. Try using `if` / `else` or [early returns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement) aggressively to avoid running any unnecessary code. Especially if such code may cause the function to recurse again.